# How to use time delay with input functions?

Tags: c

Functions like `delay(msec)` and `sleep(sec)` delay the program for the specified number of time but only after the control passes to it. For example, using the `printf()` function immediately before `delay()`, first executes `printf()` and then `delay()`. However, if we use `scanf()`, `getchar()` and other input handling functions,the control does not pass to `delay()` until I input. Right?

Is there a way to execute `scanf()` for a specified time and then exit after the completion of time even if no input is fed? Is there any function to execute `scanf()` or any other input functions for only a specified period of time?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that as your program has a single thread, a `sleep()` that follows a `scanf()` would not be executed until the `scanf()` has concluded.

I think what you are trying to do is to read a string, waiting for a time limit. The solution to this is to build your string to be scanned separately (whilst checking that the time limit has not expired), then pass the string to `sscanf()` (note additional `s`) for later processing.

The first bit is the hard part. Probably the easiest way to do this is to use a loop and `select()` on `STDIN` (i.e. the input stream) with a small timeout. Every time a character arrives, add it to the string. You will need to process (e.g.) delete manually. Read the time with `gettimeofday` and if the difference between this and the start time exceeds a given timeout, then exit on the basis you have timed out.

An alternative approach would be to use an alarm handler with `SIGALRM`. You may (or may not) find this terminates an `fgets()` satisfactorilly. You will need a `sigaction` without `SA_RESTART`. With a following wind, that should work. I say 'with a following wind' as there appear to be buggy c library versions out there that unconditionally retry when `EINTR` is received. See for instance: http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~dank/sigtest.c

Of course there may be libraries that help you here. `readline` does not have an inbuilt timeout. `editline` might.

Comment: How can I do a select() on stdin?Thanks

Comment: `STDIN` is associated with file descriptor 0. Use `FD_SET` and `select()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, don't know about the other platforms, but there is a workaround for Windows users: Under `Windows.h`, there is this `GetKeyState( keyID )`, allowing checks for the state of keyboard keys.

Here's an actualization I've made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void PrintKey( int * key ) {

    /* initially lowercase */
    int lowercase = 1;

    /* if shift is being held, indicated by the leftmost bit
    invert the lowercase boolean */
    if ( ( GetKeyState( VK_SHIFT ) & 0x8000 ) == 0x8000 ) lowercase ^= 1;

    /* if Caps Lock is toggled, indicated by the rightmost bit
    invert the lowercase boolean (again) */
    if ( ( GetKeyState( VK_CAPITAL ) & 0x0001 ) == 0x0001 ) lowercase ^= 1;

    /* print the key */
    if ( *key > '9' && lowercase ) putchar( *key + 'a' - 'A' );
    else putchar( *key );

}

int main( )
{
    int timeout = 10000;                /* timeout (in milliseconds) */
    char keysheld['Z' + 1] = { 0 };     /* record of keys being held (1: being hold, 0: released) */
    int lastkeyonhold = 0;              /* last key that has been pressed */
    int holddelay;                      /* delay before repeating starts (in millisec) */
    int repeatperiod = 40;              /* how much before each repeat (in millisec) */

    while ( timeout > 0 ) {
    /* until timeout */

        /* check keys from 0 to Z */
        for ( int i = '0'; i <= 'Z'; i++ ) {
            if ( i == '9' + 1 ) i = 'A';

            /* 0x8000 is the leftmost bit for 2 bytes...
            leftmost bit is given as 1, if the key is being pressed */
            if ( ( GetKeyState( i ) & 0x8000 ) == 0x8000 ) {

                /* if the key wasn't already being known as held
                make it known as the last key that has been pressed
                refresh the delay record to 500 milliseconds
                and print the key once */
                if ( !keysheld[i] ) {
                    lastkeyonhold = i;
                    holddelay = 500;
                    PrintKey( &i );
                }

                /* regardless, make the key known as pressed */
                keysheld[i] = 1;
            }

            /* if the key is not being hold, make it known so
            this is important, because this is what will allow us to have
            a freshly pressed key to be our lastkeyonhold */
            else keysheld[i] = 0;
        }

        /* if the console window is the active window */
        if ( GetConsoleWindow( ) == GetForegroundWindow( ) ) {

            /* and the last key pressed is still being pressed */
            if ( keysheld[lastkeyonhold] ) {
                /* and the hold delay is over... then repeatedly print the key */
                if ( holddelay < 0 ) PrintKey( &lastkeyonhold );
                /* else, just keep on consuming the delay */
                else holddelay -= repeatperiod;
            }

            /* if return has been pressed while the console window is active
            break out... */
            if ( ( GetKeyState( VK_RETURN ) & 0x8000 ) == 0x8000 ) {
                break;
            }

        }

        Sleep( repeatperiod );
        timeout -= repeatperiod;
    }

    /* print a New Line ('\n' or 10, whatever) after breaking out, for whatever reason */
    putchar( 10 );
    system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

It basically just replicates what you'd have on any text editor if you were to press or press-and-hold your keyboard keys, by detecting the keyboard-key's states. You may read the comments in the code for detailed explanation.

It only does it for the letters and numerical keys above the letters unfortunately... I could very well add the number pad keys, but it would be troublesome to manage the locational keys by hand. I don't know if there is an easier way to do it for the rest of the keys, other than managing all the buttons by hand. For the whole list of Virtual Keys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx